# MySQL creating IF Query to show which Tier Col_A is in

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I'm trying to create a query where the values in Col_A will be considered when defining which Tier it belongs to.

Here's my non-working query:

> SELECT *,
>
> (IF Col_A < 25, Tier = 1,
>
> IF Col_A >= 25 AND < 50, Tier = 2,
>
> IF Col_A >= 50 AND < 75, Tier = 3,
>
> Tier = 4) AS Tier FROM Table1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) for this:

```
SELECT *,
  CASE
    WHEN Col_A < 25 THEN 1
    WHEN Col_A >= 25 AND Col_A < 50 THEN 2
    WHEN Col_A >= 50 AND Col_A < 75 THEN 3
    ELSE 4
  END AS Tier
FROM Table1
```